# Dividir el resultado de dos consultas en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, vistas

Buen día,

Me gustaría saber si alguien puede ayudarme o explicarme de qué manera puedo hacer la división del resultado de una consulta con otra en MySQL.

La primera consulta es:

```
select count(*)  from actovoto  where participo = 1
```

La segunda consulta es:

```
select count(*)  from actovoto
```

Hice algo más o menos así. Realmente no conozco mucho sobre MySQL y tampoco se si la función UNION pueda ayudarme:

```
select T1/T2
from actovoto
where (
    (select count(*)  from actovoto where participo = 1) as T1
union
    (select count(*)  from actovoto) as T2
)
```

Necesito dividir el resultado de la primera entre la segunda y expresarla como porcentaje. Esto formará parte de unas vistas que estoy haciendo para una tarea.

Muchas gracias a quien pueda colaborar conmigo.

Comment: @BetaM mo he intentado nada aún. He buscado, pero no he encontrado nada que se parezca. Lo más parecido que he encontrado es el uso de la función UNION para unir resultados de consultas, pero no encuentro nada que indique cómo hacer la operación que necesito.

Comment: Listo @BetaM, editada la pregunta con lo que creo que se debe hacer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Puedes asignar cada una de las consultas a variables de esta forma:

   ```
   @consultaConteoCondicionado = (select count(*)  from actovoto  where participo = 1);
   @consultaConteo = (select count(*)  from actovoto);
   ```

Cuando ejecutes estas consultas no verás de forma inmediata el resultado, puedes emplear un `SELECT`

2. Para obtener la salida de ambas variables dividiéndolas procede de esta forma:

   ```
   SELECT @consultaConteoCondicionado / @consultaConteo;
   ```

**Referencia**

- [Variables de usuario definidas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-user-variables.html)

Answer (score 2):

el divisor es el conteo de todas las filas. El dividendo es el conteo de todas las filas donde se cumple la condición X. En otras palabras, es la suma de 1 donde se cumple + 0 donde no se cumple

```
select    sum(if(participo = 1, 1, 0)) /    count(*) from actovoto
```

mal que mal el **`count(*)`** es la suma de todas las filas, o sea **`sum(1)`**

Comment: Que buena respuesta además bien explicada

Comment: gracias por el reconocimiento @BetaM

Comment: Muchas gracias, @ffflabs. Me queda muy clara tu explicación. De hecho, no sabía que también se podían usar condicionales para MySQL. Me sirvió de mucho. Gracias, gracias, gracias